# Convert hex numbers from unsigned char to string

Tags: c++, string, hex, unsigned-char

I have an array of unsigned chars with hex values and I need to make a string of them. So when I have `arr[0]=2b` and `arr[1]=fc` I want to be able to make a string `s="2bfc"`, not the characters from ascii codes. How can I do that?

Comment: problem decomposition + googling = skill

Comment: `0x2B12` is too large to be an `unsigned char` which is one byte or `0-255` in decimal or `0-FF` in hex. Your welcome.

Comment: yup, I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You could change to long or int and loop through adding `+arr[ArrayIndex]*0x10^ArrayIndex` to get one int representation of it using `itoa()`, then convert the int to a literal string of it. Just to outline a manual process of doing it.

Comment: You can do exponentiation however you like.